# How to fill screen using a tiny png as a overlay on react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

So I have this tiny square png (8px) and I'm looking to fill a screen that has a linearGradient as a background.

This is the code I have on my view.tsx

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

import Pattern from '../../assets/icon/pattern.png';


class Test extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        headerShown: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['#060CED', '#c10c90']}
                start={{ x: 1.0, y: 0.0 }} end={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}>

                <ImageBackground
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    source={Pattern}
                    resizeMode='repeat'
                />

            </LinearGradient>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

And this is the result I get:

[image: Crappy result]

And as far as my testing has gone, apparently even If I set width to 100% and height to 100%, the ImageBackground only renders 12.5 times with this 8px by 8px png.

Another attempt I did was repeating the ImageBackground and having Linear Gradiend as a flex with `flex-wrap`.
The result is this:

[image: Crappy result]

As expected, one side of the screen is left blanks as the flex-wrap enters in action. And this even shows weird artifacts on every repetition. 
Even finding the correct resolution won't be the solution, as this should be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [demo](https://snack.expo.io/BJOWDb3xI)

```
<ImageBackground
   source={Pattern}
  style={{        
     flex: 1,
     width: null,
    height: null}}
/>
```

Comment: without the resizeMode the pattern is scaled up thus showing the lines way too strong.